# My CSS and JS files won't apply to deployment

Tags: css, django, heroku, deployment, static-files

I've tried - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
and it won't work.

The logs tell me this:

post-processed (other static files)

post-processed 'app.js'

post-processed 'style.css'

63 static files copied to /app/staticfiles, 63 post-processed

verifying deploy... done.

Then when I run heroku open, the app still looks all bare bones. Help would be greatly appreciated! Here is the stuff in settings.py

`PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'staticfiles/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/'),`
)

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the page, and verifying that your links are set up properly?

Comment: What do you mean? I am currently at a loss at what is going on. I searched through quite a few forums/stackoverflow posts and nothing worked.

Comment: Using a browser inspector...For example, in Chrome, you can call it up by `Ctrl + Shift + i`

Comment: The title for the css link says "Page not found at /static/style.css" What should I do?

Comment: What are your `STATICFILES_DIRS`, `STATIC_URL`, AND `STATIC_ROOT` in **settings.py**?

Comment: updated my post to reflect this!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66232/discussion-between-sticky-and-rnevius).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to point a url in `urls.py` at the `STATIC_ROOT`.

`STATIC_ROOT` should be the same as `STATICFILES_DIRS`.
eg.

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'static_assets'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static_assets'),
)
```

`STATIC_URL` on the other hand is where Heroku puts static files after calling `collectstatic`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the **settings.py** settings show in the link you pointed to, you won't have issues like this. You definitely have an issue with your `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATICFILES_DIRS`. Your settings should look like the following:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)
```